# Comparing two tables in hsqldb

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have two tables loaded into hsqldb (file db) from two different databases.

The structure of both the tables are same.

However, it might be possible that some keys present in Table A are missing in Table B and vice versa.

I want to create a report comparing both the tables.

What would be the best approach to achieve this ?

My current implementation will create maps of comparison and will out it on to excel sheet using POI. Is it the best approach ?

Is there any existing example depicting such scenario any where on web ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JOINS`. As per the [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/guide.html#N10372), hsqldb supports basic joins. Please note that performance of the query depends on other factors like the amount of data any other constraints in the query etc.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if I can efficiently use this.

Answer (score 0):

if you assuming that keys will be missing in one or the other then why don't you use sql to find them?

```
select id from a where a.id not in select id from b;
```

(Not Tested)